# PyBrain LSTM Example resultin in ValueError:Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python, neural-network, directory-structure, pybrain, lstm

I'm trying to run an LSTM network for like two weeks now and I cant find a good framework to do so. I'm actually trying with PyBrain which has this directory hierarchy:

```
pybrain/
    ...
    examples/
        ...
        supervised/
            ...
            neuralnets+svm/
                ...
                example_rnn.py
```

but I'm getting this relative import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example_fnn.py", line 14, in <module>
from .datasets import generateGridData, generateClassificationData, plotData
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

when make the call like this:

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:neuralnets+svm lucaslourenco$ python example_fnn.py
```

some of the answers about this same error say that I should make the call from the parent directory using the `-m` flag, like:

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:pybrain lucaslourenco$ python -m examples.supervised.neuralnets+svm.example_fnn
```

When I do it, I get this:

```
/Users/lucaslourenco/anaconda/bin/python: No module named examples.supervised.neuralnets+svm
```

- Am I just doing a simple mistake on the `-m` flag call?
- There is a simple way of correcting this without making changes on the framework(you know how bad can be the results of modifying a framework)?
- There are other options of frameworks to run an LSTM example in OSX or W7, preferable in python?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change "from .datasets import" on top of the file to "from datasets import"

ideally the code wants to use a function from datagenerator.py and the location of the datasets folder does not seem to require the relative location i.e. .datasets.

I deduced the answer by looking at other examples pybrain/examples/supervised/backprop/parityrnn.py

While you are at it you might also run into touble with pylab, it seems that the location of functions like show, hold etc. have changed to matplotlib.pyplot instead of pylab